# Вопрос о реализация чата

Tags: java, android, android-studio, сокет

Есть простой чат на андроиде и сервер на Ява.Соеденение между ними происходит с помощью сокета. На андроиде при создании активити создаеться и запускается AsyncTask который во втором потоке в бесконечном цикле читает данные. Меня мучают некотырие вопросы о реализации общения клиента и сервера. 
1. Все ли я правильно реализовал на данный момент.
2. Когда сервер отдает массив cообщений ( json ) при каждый итерации бесконечного цикла, нужно выдовать все сообщения, несколько последних или одну последнию. Подскажите логику отправки сообщений сервера. Как обьяснить серверу что нужно отправлять а что нет. 
3. Когда пользователь ввел сообщения и нажал на кнопку отправки то как передать во второй поток инфу, в метод doInBackground.
4. На сервере для каждого пользователя создаеться свой поток. Если озу на компьютере выделенно например 1гб много ли он выдержет потоков?
5. Нужно данные(имя пользовате) отправлять при каждый итерации или можно один раз отправить и держать их в потоке созданного для пользователя на сервере.

Могу предоставить код но думаю на врятли это кому нужно будет. Для злых дядек которые ругаются на чайников изза того что они просят много сразу говорю я не прошу код просто хочу понять логику,  понять как это все реализовать. А сам я только начал изучать сокеты.

Comment: по п.4 посмотрите в сторону асинхронного ввода вывода. Поток на каждого клиента слишком жирно. один поток спокойно может обрабатывать около 1000 клиентов (если не требуются серьезные вычисления, а только ввод-вывод). После чего вы упретесь в максимальное количество открытых файлов(сокетов) на процесс (на большинстве ОС 4096). Если соединений предполагается больше, я бы рекомендовал перейти на udp, так как он не требует отдельного сокета на каждого клиента, но это несколько усложнит прикладной протокол

Comment: по п.2 если уж на каждого клиента целый поток (а даже если и нет) у вас есть некая информация о клиентах, в этой информации у себя сервер может помнить, что последнее он отсылал клиенту и отсылать только новое. При подключении нового клиента сами решите какую порцию начальных данных ему выдать

Comment: п. 5 если соединение постоянно установлено, то конечно имя можно спокойно хранить на сервере и не передавать каждый раз. И это надежней с точки зрения безопасности, клиент не сможет подделать чужое имя после того как установил соединение. Если решите читая первый коммент перейти на udp, то возможно надо будет передавать в каждом пакете (хотя с другой стороны север все равно сможет помнить клиента по его связке ip:порт)

Comment: @Mike udp конечно круто но все же мне нравиться что для каждого юзара будет отдельный  поток где они будут работать индивидуально пересекаясь с другими потоками лишь в базе данных. Как я понял это со стороны оптимизации очень не правильно но на пока что пойдет думаю. Если что сделаю как вы сказали. Выдержит ли одновременно скажем 100 или 200 потоков cлабенький впс?

Comment: п. 4 количество сокетов зависит не то ОС, а от настроек. Выделять на каждый сокет отдельный поток - это нормальная практика. п. 2 Логика отправки/получения сообщений обычная: пользователь заходит в чат, ему прилетает последние 30 сообщений. Для рассылки сообщений клиентам можно выбрать два решения: моментальная рассылка, когда один клиент пишет, а другим сразу прилетает. И второй, когда сервер помещает сообщения в какой-то стек и отправляет их с определенной периодичностью.

Comment: @lampa спасибо. Вы уже не в первый раз помогаете мне в изучении сокетов

Comment: Ну все равно не все обьяснилось

Comment: Я здесь просто поделюсь о своем наборе клиент части и отвечу на пару вопросов. Я использую okHttp websocket без AsyncTask и бесконечного цикла, просто принимаю ответ в onMessage() и передаю его в слушатель  который я реализовал в активити, по оптимизации все отлично. По поводу вопроса 4, 1гб рам выглядит слабо. По поводу  вопроса 5 ответьте что вы используете для реализации сервер части (мне интересно) а так, храните на сервере, это намного безопаснее.

Comment: @sakuraso13 Хоть и работал над этим давно и это уже не актуально но если интересно сервак стоял на java socket

Answer (score 0):

Возможно к данной реализации не подойдёт, но как на счёт посмотреть в сторону Akka cluster? На акторах логика подобных асинхронных штук пишется довольно просто. У нас на них джуны чат писали в качестве тестового задания, получалось что-то такое: https://github.com/AlexeyDialex/AkkaChat (правда пример на scala)

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос